# Android SQLLite, Syntax error when trying to get data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I've this

> 11-19 19:16:38.920: E/SQLiteLog(5568): (1) near "SELECT ": syntax
>   error

error on android select query and then my app crash, I'm not able to understand why it happen.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIA;
            Log.e("DB", "select query "+selectQuery);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Log.e("DB", "db "+db);
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOMECATEGORIA)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                        id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID));
                        color=c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COLORE));
                        return color;
                    }
                    coloriusati.add(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COLORE)));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: What is the crash you see in logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is double space after your SELECT command.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIA;
```

Remove the extra space after 'SELECT' and it should work.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIA;
```

Comment: Double regular spaces don't cause the error. If the first space is e.g. a non-breaking space, that would explain OP's problem and why this fixes it.